# Nemo file manager - Context menu - Actions

Tags: icons, nemo, context-menu, nautilus-actions

- I have Ubuntu 20.4.
- I have installed Nemo file manager to manage the desktop icons.
- I have added a custom action.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- Enable icons for the Nemo Context menu (Icons are not displayed in the main menu, only in the submenu, like the 'Open with' submenu)
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGTvn.jpg)
- Create nested actions in the Nemo Context Menu or group actions somehow (Similar to the 'Open With' menu|)

I have searched for many hours with no luck.
It would be awesome if someone could help me.

Thank you

Comment: Or at least some guidance for how I can do it myself.
I'm a developer and I'm happy to give it a try.
Thanx

Comment: Seems to be disabled/stripped in Ubuntu 20.04(Gnome). Asked a similar question and got no valid answers - users don't even seem to realize it... Distros like Linux Mint ,Arch Linux,Manjaro or Fedora are supporting it - looks like to be another fantastic Gnome feature.

Comment: Have you figured any of the questions out, especially the first one, after two years?